# Filtering a custom post type by custom taxonomy in archive template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives, categories

I've seen this question posted in different forms before, but most of those solutions are centered around the admin interface, and I haven't found any answers that apply to the front end.

I've got a custom post type, and an associated custom taxonomy. I'm using the archive page (`archive-{custom_type}.php`) to display the items, and using `wp_list_categories` to show a list of the custom taxonomy terms. I can manually alter the posts displayed by adding a `tax_query` parameter to the `WP_Query` call, but the problem I'm running into is I cannot figure out how to alter the taxonomy links so they point to this archive page so I can filter dynamically. I'd rather not duplicate this template's markup and code in a `taxonomy-{custom_type}.php` file.

Do I need to just output the taxonomy links manually? How should the URL be structured so I can get the query param? I have `query_var => true` set and a rewrite rule on the custom taxonomy definition, but haven't been able to get `get_query_var()` to return anything.

The end result should be a template that can list all items in the custom post type, or filter those items by their associated custom taxonomy.

Comment: I frequently need this on sites and I always find it neater to duplicate the template. To prevent duplicate code though, you can use get_template_part() to pull a common piece of PHP into both templates, or even to pull one template into the other.

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have **"book"** post type and **"genre"** taxonomy.
And you want to get books with genre of **"scifi"**.

You can pass the parameter in the url using:

```
?taxonomy=genre&term=scifi
```

Then you can get those parameter using `get_query_var('taxonomy')` and `get_query_var('term')` and add them to the WP_Query arguments.

```
$taxonomy = get_query_var('taxonomy');
$term = get_query_var('term');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'terms'    => $term,
        )
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

First I have taxonomy "**service**".

Here I make a different php file, for the taxonomy "**service**" loop and the default WordPress loop (**post**).

which will be called in **archive.php**

it will look the same

First I will create a file for the "**service**" taxonomy named **my-loop-service.php**

Fill in the code:

```
<div class="my-service">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <div <?php post_class('my-service-loop'); ?>>
           <h1 class="my-service-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
     </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

Secondly I make a file for the default **post loop** with the name **my-loop-post.php**

Fill in the code:

```
<div class="my-post">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <div <?php post_class('my-post-loop'); ?>>
           <h1 class="my-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
     </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

And the following is the contents of the **archive.php** file

```
<?php 
get_header();

if (is_post_type_archive('service') || is_tax('services-category') || is_tax('services-tags')){
    get_template_part('my-loop-service'); // Get Loop for Taxonomy service
} else {
   get_template_part('my-loop-post'); // Default Loop for Post

}

    // Navigation
    echo '<div id="my-navigation">';
    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'mid_size' => 2,
        'prev_text' => __( 'Prev', 'text-domain' ),
        'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'text-domain' ),
    ));
    echo '</div>';

get_footer(); 
?>
```

**That way there is no need to create a special php archive file for your taxonomy.**