# Pagination is not working in custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I want to add pagination in single page of custom post type.

This is the code for single page (custom post type):

```
<?php
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array('post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'paged' => $paged);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

// Loop

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<div id="pagination" class="clearfix">
    <?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $loop->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );//posts_nav_link(); ?>
</div>

////

Function page code ////


////

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'news',
        array('labels' => array(
            'name' => __('News', 'post type general name'), /* This is the Title of the Group */
            'singular_name' => __('News', 'post type singular name'), /* This is the individual type */
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'custom post type item'), /* The add new menu item */
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New'), /* Add New Display Title */
            'edit' => __( 'Edit' ), /* Edit Dialog */
            'edit_item' => __('Edit'), /* Edit Display Title */
            'new_item' => __('New '), /* New Display Title */
            'view_item' => __('View'), /* View Display Title */
            'search_items' => __('Search news'), /* Search Custom Type Title */
            'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found in the Database.'), /* This displays if there are no entries yet */
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'), /* This displays if there is nothing in the trash */
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        ), /* end of arrays */
            'description' => __( 'This is the example custom post type' ), /* Custom Type Description */
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_position' => 2, /* this is what order you want it to appear in on the left hand side menu */
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news', 'with_front' => true ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            /* the next one is important, it tells what's enabled in the post editor */
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to start with a new Query in archive.php loop

Only need to create a different loop file for the custom taxonomy and default loop post

See here for more details [Filtering a custom post type by custom taxonomy in archive template](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/226923/filtering-a-custom-post-type-by-custom-taxonomy-in-archive-template/352422#352422)

example I have taxonomy "service"

archive.php file

```
<?php 
get_header();

if (is_post_type_archive('service') || is_tax('services-category') || is_tax('services-tags')){
    get_template_part('my-loop-service'); // Get Loop for Taxonomy service
} else {
   get_template_part('my-loop-post'); // Default Loop for Post

}

    // Navigation
    echo '<div id="my-navigation">';
    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'mid_size' => 2,
        'prev_text' => __( 'Prev', 'text-domain' ),
        'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'text-domain' ),
    ));
    echo '</div>';

get_footer(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions

```
next_posts_link
```

and

```
previous_posts_link
```

should be called before you reset the post data.

Answer (score 0):

Reset query after pagination link
Try this:

```
<?php
    $paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array('post_type' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'paged' => $paged);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>

// Loop

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div id="pagination" class="clearfix">
    <?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $loop->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );//posts_nav_link(); ?>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_query();  ?>
```

Comment: Not Working.. I've added same code

Answer (score 0):

`next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` both check `is_single` and prevent output in that case. They are intended for archive pages and will not work on singular views.